# UIImage from a Off Screen view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

dear developer i want make an image from an offscreen view.

when i start my app the first view is the RootViewController and everthing
works fine.

when i go to an other view and make this.

```
RootViewController *root = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];

UIImage *screenShot = [self imageWithView: root.tableView];

(UIImage *) imageWithView:(UIView *)view

{

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, YES, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]); 
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;

}
```

The app crash in the "imageWithView:(UIView *)view" function at the line
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

the log says
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'ListItem''

and this happen in the rootviewcontroller on the line

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ListItem" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

somebody an idea?

Comment: I'm not going to comment on your code but the error message means you are either mispelling the name of your coredata entity OR you are not passing the managedObjectContext from your App delegate to your view controller. In other words this has nothing to do with your 'UIImage from an offscreen view' question.

Comment: thx for the answer... i think its the second point...how and where do i have passing the managedObjectContext to an other view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Rog said there is probably no context. Here is the code that create the one correctly:

```
-(NSManagedObjectContext*) managedContext {
    @synchronized( self ) {
        if( !_managedObjectContext) {
            _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
            [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: [VIDataManager sharedManager].persistentStoreCoordinator];
        }
    }

    return _managedObjectContext;
}

-(NSPersistentStoreCoordinator*) persistentStoreCoordinator {
    @synchronized( self ) {
        if( !_persistentStoreCoordinator ) {
            NSLog(@"init _persistentStoreCoordinator");
            NSError *error = nil;
            _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel];

            if( ![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL: databaseURL() options:nil error: &error] ) {
            }
        }
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;    
}

-(NSManagedObjectModel*) managedObjectModel {
    @synchronized( self ) {
        if( !_managedObjectModel ) {
            NSLog(@"init _managedObjectModel");
            NSURL* modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Datamodel" withExtension:@"mom"];
            _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: modelURL];
        }
    }

    return _managedObjectModel;

}
```

And in @interface you have to declare 3 ivars and properties:

```
    NSManagedObjectContext*             _managedObjectContext;
    NSManagedObjectModel*               _managedObjectModel;
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator*       _persistentStoreCoordinator;

@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext*          managedContext;
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSManagedObjectModel*            managedObjectModel;
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator*    persistentStoreCoordinator;
```